# How can I parse downloaded CSV data with Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to download a *.csv* file into an array and then parse each column line-by-line with Text::CSV. I have the following:

```
my @file = get("http://www.someCSV.com/file.csv") or warn $!;

my $CSV = Text::CSV->new();
$CSV->sep_char (',');

for ( @file ) {

  $CSV->parse($_) or warn $!;

      my @columns = $CSV->fields();
      print $columns[0] . "\n";
 }
```

Rather than downloading the file, saving it and then slurping it into a filehandle, I thought it would be more efficient to just put the CSV file into an array and parse from there. However, the above code doesn't work and I don't understand why. I get "Warning: something's wrong at test.pl"; not very helpful, to say the least.

This is more for learning. I don't have to do it this way but it's just bugging me why I'm not able to use Text::CSV with an array.

Comment: What's the `get` function? From `LWP::UserAgent`? Did you confirm `@file`'s elements are lines from `file.csv`?

Comment: I am assuming that `get` is from `LWP::UserAgent`? In general, you should post the `use XXX` part of your code. One `get` isn't the same as another...

Comment: The not very useful "something's wrong" error is because you didn't actually tell perl to give you a useful error. `$!` is only set when a system call fails, calls to modules don't normally set `$!`. It's always good practice when `warn` ing or `die` ing to include descriptive text along with any applicable error variables. Like `... or warn 'get failed';` and `... or warn 'parse failed';`. The more descriptive the better. `$!` is omitted because it will probably not be set by get or parse (but check their docs to verify). In rafl's answer you would still want to include it on the call to open

Comment: Always show complete demonstration programs, and remember to always show us some sample input. We can't reliably guess what's going on. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `LWP::Simple`'s `get` function there. That doesn't return a list of lines of the response body, but a string containing the response body. So at first, you probably meant:

```
my $content = get($uri);
```

You could now go and read that line by line, passing each line to `Text::CSV`s `parse` method. That might appear to work in some cases, but as CSV files may contain embedded newlines, it won't be very reliable.

Instead, let `Text::CSV` figure out what exactly is a line in the input by passing it a filehandle it can read from by itself. To do that, there's no need to save the file locally. You can just open a handle to a string:

```
open my $fh, '<', \$content or die $!;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    my @fields = @{ $row };
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you run into these sorts of problems, look at the data you have before you continue to the next step.