# Perl - Using an Array on a Config txt file

Tags: perl

So I have a text file with four sets of data on a line, such as `aa bb username password`. So far I have been able to parse through the first line of the file using substrings and indices, and assigning each of the four to variables.

My goal is to use an array and chomp through each line and assign them to the four variables, and than to match an user inputted argument to the first variable, and use the four variables in that correct line.

For example, this would be the text file:

```
"aa bb cc dd"
"ee ff gg hh"
```

And depending on whether the user inputs "aa" or "ee" as the argument, it would use that line's set of arguments in the code.

I am trying to get up a basic array and chomp through it based on a condition for the first variable, essentially.

Here is my code for the four variables for the first line, but like I said, this only works for the first line in the text file:

```
local $/;
open(FILE, $configfile) or die "Can't read config file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
my $document = <FILE>; 
close (FILE);  



my $string = $document;
my $substring = " ";

my $Index = index($string, $substring);
my $aa = substr($string, 0, $Index);
my $newstring = substr($string, $Index+1);

my $Index2 = index($newstring, $substring); 
my $bb = substr($newstring, 0, $Index2);
my $newstring2 = substr($newstring, $Index2+1);

my $Index3 = index($newstring2, $substring);
my $cc = substr($newstring2, 0, $Index3);
my $newstring3 = substr($newstring2, $Index3+1);

my $Index4 = index($newstring3, $substring);
my $dd = substr($newstring3, 0, $Index4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can parse your whole line using [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) instead of running index and substring on them:

```
my ( $aa, $bb, $cc, $dd ) = split /\s+/, $line;
```

Even better, use an array:

```
my @array = split /\s+/, $line;
```

I think you're saying that you need to store each array of command parts into another array of lines. Is that correct? Take a look at this [tutorial on references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) available in the Perl Documentation.

Perl has three different types of variables. The problem is that each of the types of variables of these stores only a single piece of data. Arrays and hashes may store lots of data, but only one piece of data can be stored in each element of a hash or array.

References allow you to get around this limitation. A reference is simply a pointer to another piece of data. For example, if `$line` = `aa bb cc dd`, doing this:

```
 my @command_list = split /\s+/ $line;
```

Will give you the following:

```
$command_list[0] = "aa";
$command_list[1] = "bb";
$command_list[2] = "cc";
$command_list[3] = "dd";
```

You want to store `@command_list` into another structure. What you need is a reference to `@command_list`. To get a reference to it, you merely put a backslash in front of it:

```
my $reference = \@command_list;
```

This could be put into an array:

```
my @array;
$array[0] = $reference;
```

Now, I'm storing an entire array into a single element of an array.

To get back to the original structure from the reference, you put the correct [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29). Since this is an array, you put `@` in front of it:

```
my @new_array = @{ $reference };
```

If you want the first item in your reference without using having to transport it into another array, you could simply treat `@{ $reference }` as an array itself:

```
${ $reference }[0] = "aa";
```

Or, use the magic `->` which makes the syntax a bit cleaner:

```
$reference->[0] = "aa";
```

Go through the tutorial. This will help you understand the full power of references, and how they can be used. Your program would look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);  #Better print that print
use autodie;          #Kills your program if the file can't be open

my $file = [...]   #Somehow get the file you're reading in...
open my $file_fh, "<", $file;
my @command_list;
while ( my $line = <$file_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @line_list = split /\s+/, $line;
    push @command_list, \@line_list;
}
```

Note that `push @command_list, \@line_list;` is pushing a reference to one array into another. How do you get it back out? Simple:

```
for my $cmd_line_ref ( @command_list ) {
    my $command = $cmd_line_ref->[0];    #This is the first element in your command
    next unless $command eq $user_desires;  # However you figure out what the user wants
    my $line = join " ", @{ $cmd_line_ref } #Rejoins your command line once again
    ???   #Profit
}
```

Read the [tutorial on references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and learn about [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) and [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the whole file in the `my $document = <FILE>` line.

Try something like:

```
my @lines;
open my $file, '<', $configfile or die 'xxx';
while( <$file> ) {
  chomp;
  push @lines, [ split ]
}
```

And now `@lines` has an array of arrays with the information you need.

(EDIT) don't forget to lose the `local $/;` -- it's what is making you read the whole file at once.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder about the `local $/;` line. I guess the primary question I have is about the array itself, how would I go about setting the four parts of the arrays to four different variables? So that I could check for the user input against variable one, to choose which array of 4 to use in the code

Comment: after the code I posted, `@lines` already has an array OF arrays... so, the first part in the first line is in `$lines[0][0]`, the second part in `$lines[0][1]`, the third in `$lines[0][1]` and the fourth in `$lines[0][3]`. The second line is in `$lines[1][...]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`my $document = <FILE>` is reading in only the first line.  Try using a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all lines of the file at once - assuming it's a small file - you may want to use `File::Slurp` module:

```
use File::Slurp;
my @lines = File::Slurp::read_file($configfile);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    # do whatever
```

Also, you can use CPAN modules to split the strings into fields.

If they are single-space separated, simply read the whole file using a standard CSV parser (you can configure `Text::CSV_XS` to use any characater as separator). Example here: [How can I parse downloaded CSV data with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851905/how-can-i-parse-downloaded-csv-data-with-perl)

If they are separated by random amount of whitespace, use @massa's advice below and use `split` function.

Comment: You could even do `my @lines = map [ split ], read_file $configfile` :-D